# How to use an Unorder List as multiselect and send selected items in form MVC 5?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a page where a user can subscribe in categories, so, the obvious solution is to use a multiselect control, i've test it with ListBox (HtmlHelper) but you have to select by clicking control, so i found a good Bootstrap control [list-group] i've add a jQuery code to add [active] class to select item that's the code

### Markup

```
  <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</a>
  </div>
```

### Js

```
$('.list-group a').on('click',function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
```

My question here: **How to use this control in a form in Asp.NET MVC 5 to get all the selected items and if the user already had selected some items and he want to go back to edit it, How i can show him what he already have selected ??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to use a ListBoxFor and bind to an array / enumerable property in your model.

For example, have a model like this:

```
public class ViewModel(){
      public string[] SelectedItems
      public string[] AvailableItems
}
```

Then in your view, use ListBoxFor like so:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedItems, new SelectList(Model.AvailableItems))
```

Finally, to prevent people from having to hold control to select multiple items, add this javascript

```
$('option').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('selected', !$(this).prop('selected'));
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I too dislike having to hold control to select multiple items on a multi-select list.

However, rather than use `<a>`-tags, where "selected" values are not posted to the server, I would recommend you stick with Multi-Select List and simply use a jQuery plugin to style and change the UI behavior.

Quick Googling I was able to find several options: http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/multiple-select

UPDATE:

I was able to also find multi-selects that work with Bootstrap 3:
http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#examples

Comment: I dont want to have it in a Dropdown, i want the user can see all the categories and then select it !!